# Is using the SysRQ Emergency Remount an acceptable way to clone hard disk?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, ext4, magic-sysrq

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu) and I was told that I can use the method described below to clone the system's hard drive to another one - to plug into a new machine. (Without booting from a Live CD)

It assumes that the system's disk is `/dev/sda`, the partition mounted as root is `/dev/sda1`, and an empty disk to clone it to is `/dev/sdb`.

`echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger`
Remounts all filesystems including the one mounted as root read-only.

`e2fsck -fy /dev/sda1`
Corrects the filesystem errors caused by forcing the R/O remount.

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` clones the disk to the empty one.

`e2fsck -fy /dev/sdb1` fixes the newly cloned filesystem. At this step it usually tells about fixed block checksums.

`reboot -f`
Reboots the system. At this step I disconnect the newly cloned disk, and plug it into a new PC.

I've used this method two times, and all machines are working fine, but I'm afraid that doing that could cause some dangerous filesystem issues? If yes, why? And should I avoid using this method to clone hard disks in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to create an LVM snapshot of the filesystem and then use the snapshot as the source for making the copy. That has two benefits:

- it doesn't require rebooting the system when you are done
- it flushes and syncs the filesystem so you don't have inconsistent/corrupt metadata

Failing that, if you are already willing to reboot your system to make a copy, then you could shut down cleanly and boot into single-user mode (add `single` on the kernel command line from grub, `ro` should already be there) and then use `dd` to copy the source disk to the target.  In single-user mode the root partition is already mounted read-only so no problems with inconsistent on-disk (meta)data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about filesystem issues, but i usually just used rsync to "clone" my harddisk. This has the advantage of starting with an empty filesystem (which could be of another size or type), so all your files will get defragemented during the copy. Before copying everything to the new disk, i just shutdown important services like fetchmail/samba/anything that writes data i care about so i wouldn't lose any data.
Specific command:
`rsync -axAX / /mnt/newDisk/`.
This does not preserve hardlinks, if that is important to you, you'd need to add -H.

Comment: How exactly you used cp? To clone the disk (like `cp /dev/sda /dev/sdb`), or just to copy the files from one filesystem to another?

Comment: @melonfsck you can't copy the block devices with `cp`, that is essentially what `dd` is doing. I suspect something like `cp -a` is being used, but `rsync` is better in that case because it is multi-threaded and can be restarted if interrupted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @melonfsck I added an example command. And i actually use rsync, i thought cp would work as well, but cp apparently doesn't clone special files like FIFOs, so it's probably just better to use rsync.